# Python: import variable from main file at package module

Tags: python

i try to use a complex structure in flask restfull, my structure is the following:

```
main.py
-models
-- __init__.py
--modelA.py
-resources
--__init__.py
--resourceA.py
```

I have a variable in main.py and i need this variable in models.modelA and i need also models.modelA in resources.resourceA. At this point everything is ok. When i start my app, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from resources.resourceA import functionA
  File "/var/www/project/resources/resourceA.py", line 11, in <module>
    from models.modelA import *
  File "/var/www/project/models/modelA.py", line 8, in <module>
    from main import mainvariable
  File "/var/www/project/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from resources.resourceA import functionA
ImportError: cannot import name functionA
```

I hope your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you basically have here is called a circular import. As the traceback states, your `main` module is importing `functionA` from `resources.resourceA`. And `resourceA` is importing `models.modelA` which is in turn trying to import `main` which again requires `resources.resourceA`.

Unless a particular order is resolved, python interpreter cannot understand how to resolve the modules. You can however solve this problem in an easier way.

If the `models.modelA` doesn't require a module level import for `main`, you can shift the import to the function / class scope where you need its imports.

See here for more on [circular imports](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).

Comment: Thank, it works for me. I put the import of models.ModelA at the end of resources.resourceA and everything is fine.